# pandas sort DataFrame based on object, and datetime columns?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm having trouble simply sorting a pandas dataframe first by a column with a string then by datetime column.  when doing so, the dates returned are out of order.  What am I doing wrong?

df looks like

```
                  Date  Field 1
0  2013-07-01 00:00:00        1
1  2013-07-02 00:00:00        1
2  2013-07-03 00:00:00        1
3  2013-07-03 00:00:00        2
4  2013-07-05 00:00:00        2
5  2013-07-05 00:00:00        1
6  2013-07-08 00:00:00        2
7  2013-07-09 00:00:00        2
8  2013-07-11 00:00:00        2
9  2013-07-12 00:00:00        2
10 2013-07-15 00:00:00        1
11 2013-07-16 00:00:00        1
12 2013-07-17 00:00:00        1
13 2013-07-18 00:00:00        1
14 2013-07-19 00:00:00        1
```

When the dataframe was created, Date was an object, and converted to datetime using:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
```

now the dtypes are:

```
Date       datetime64[ns]
Field 1             int64
dtype: object
```

when running a

```
df.sort_index(by=['Field 1', 'Date'])
```

or

```
df.sort(['Field 1','Date'])
```

I get back:

```
                  Date  Field 1
0  2013-07-01 00:00:00        1
1  2013-07-02 00:00:00        1
2  2013-07-03 00:00:00        1
10 2013-07-15 00:00:00        1
5  2013-07-05 00:00:00        1
11 2013-07-16 00:00:00        1
12 2013-07-17 00:00:00        1
13 2013-07-18 00:00:00        1
14 2013-07-19 00:00:00        1
8  2013-07-11 00:00:00        2
9  2013-07-12 00:00:00        2
3  2013-07-03 00:00:00        2
4  2013-07-05 00:00:00        2
6  2013-07-08 00:00:00        2
7  2013-07-09 00:00:00        2
```

what I really want back is:

```
                  Date  Field 1
0  2013-07-01 00:00:00        1
1  2013-07-02 00:00:00        1
2  2013-07-03 00:00:00        1
5  2013-07-05 00:00:00        1
10 2013-07-15 00:00:00        1
11 2013-07-16 00:00:00        1
12 2013-07-17 00:00:00        1
13 2013-07-18 00:00:00        1
14 2013-07-19 00:00:00        1
3  2013-07-03 00:00:00        2
4  2013-07-05 00:00:00        2
6  2013-07-08 00:00:00        2
7  2013-07-09 00:00:00        2
8  2013-07-11 00:00:00        2
9  2013-07-12 00:00:00        2
```

Comment: With 0.11 i get your desired result, i cant replicate yours.

Comment: so this appears to be some kind of issue with the compilation of pandas of 0.11.  I had downloaded source and compiled.  however, uninstalling that and installing Canopy with precompiled pandas and other modules, the desired results are printed.  odd.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Im using a pre-build Windows installation from:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/